# Can I sort 'Unanswered/my tags' tab by date (descending)?

Tags: discussion

The `Unanswered questions/my tags` page is where I go if I want to find questions related to my interests and abilities. There is a higher probability that I might be able to answer these questions than any others, for obvious reasons.

Is there a way to sort this tab by Date (descending)?

Does anyone else see why this should be the obvious default?